# Angular accessing parent parameter in nested modules

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-routing, angular-module

I am trying to divide an Angular 12 project into (lazyload) modules, but I'm running into a problem with accessing the route parameters in one of the child routes. I have the following (simplified) module structure:

```
app.module
| settings.module
| core.module
```

I have the following route for **app.module**:

```
{ path: 'portfolio/:portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent, canActivate: [AccessGuard],
      children: [
         { path: 'settings', component: PortfolioSettings, canActivate: [PortfolioAccessGuard],
               children: [
                  { path: 'product-settings', loadChildren: () => import('./product-settings/product-settings.module').then((m) => m.ProductSettingsModule) },
         ]}
]}
```

And the following route for **product-settings.module**:

```
{ path: '', component: ProductSettingsComponent, canActivate: [PortfolioAccessGuard] },
{ path: ':product', component: ProductSettingsComponent, canActivate: [PortfolioAccessGuard], children [...] }
```

So that you could for example get the following routes:

- .../portfolio/somePortfolioId/settings
- .../portfolio/somePortfolioId/settings/product-settings
- .../portfolio/somePortfolioId/settings/product-settings/someProductId

The access guards are located in the **core.module**.

As you can see, to access the above routes, the PortfolioAccessGuard needs to pass. In this PortfolioAccessGuard I want to perform a check on the :portfolio parameter. When I access the first route, this works, with the following code:

`route.parent.parent.params.portfolio` (route is an ActivatedRouteSnapshot)

However, when I'm accessing it from the child route (via product-settings), I can't seem to find this parameter. I tried several methods with the angular ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot and Router, but I haven't found a working one. Some examples that I've tried:

- `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(values => console.log(values))` where activatedRoute is of type ActivatedRoute gives {}.
- printing `this.activatedRouteSnapshot` which is of type ActivatedRouteSnapshot gives that data, parameters, queryParams and url are empty, parent doesn't even exist.
- printing `this.router` which is of type Router shows that its property  `browserUrlTree` contains some information about the parameter I'm looking for, but I don't know how to access it.

So my struggle is the following: What is the best way to find this :portfolio parameter from accessing the last two mentioned routes?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(values => console.log(values))` you access QueryParams not Params.

Try not to get parents of the route all parmas and query params must be available in the current route snapshot.

```
Don't Use:
route.parent.parent.params.portfolio;

Try Use:
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  const id = route.params['portfolio'];
  console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access queryParams which is not defined in route as you mention above.

You can resolve on following way:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramsMap => {
  const portfolio = paramsMap.params['portfolio'];
 });
}
```

This might be helpful.

Thanks